# why is this abstract class returning fatal Error in php

Tags: php, php-5.3

```
abstract  class MyAbstractClass{
    abstract  protected function doSomeThing();
    function threeDots(){
        return  "...";
    }
}
class MyClassA extends  MyAbstractClass{
    protected function doSomeThing(){
        $this->threeDots();
    }
}
$myclass = new MyClassA();
$myclass->doSomething();
```

this is the error that is being spitted out "Fatal error: Call to protected method MyClassA::doSomething() from context in test.php on line 10 ".Iam trying to know the reason for this error.

Comment: It should be noted that this question is from the free study guide for the Zend 5.3 certification exam that you can download from http://www.zend.com/services/certification/ (download url here http://downloads.zend.com/guides/php5.3/PHP_5-3_Study_Guide_v1a.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared the function doSomething to be proteced, which means it can only be used inside parent classes, child classes or itself. You're using it outside of that.

You can try changing

```
abstract  protected function doSomeThing();
```

into

```
abstract public function doSomeThing();
```

and

```
protected function doSomeThing(){
```

into

```
public function doSomeThing() {
```

Answer (score 2):

Protected means that this method is available within the class and to class, that inherits this class. You should use Public if you want to call it from "outside".

Comment: +1 It should be added, though that the .php file you are calling from *is* outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Method is protected you can not call this method outside the class and the class which is inherited by this class.

Make it public if you want to call outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call a protected method from inside the class itself or any subclasses. I would recommend taking a look at [the visibility entry in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).